# How to grep for 2 strings (AND condition) within a block which are not in the same line and then find something else within that same block

Tags: text-processing

I wanted to know how do we `grep` for say two strings with AND condition within a block if the strings don't appear on the same line. I tried the following but they do not work for strings not in the same line:-

1. `grep 'string1.*string2\|string2.*string1' filename`
2. `grep -P '^(?=.*pattern1)(?=.*pattern2)' filename`

For example I have an xml file with the following lines:-

```
  <test-result
    exectime="2017-07-07"
    result="FAILURE"
    isdone="TRUE"
    logicalname="this.is.test1"
    duration="10050"
  >
    <test-case
      testcasename="this.is.test.case.name1"
      testunit="abcd-mc"
      testpath="file:/this/is/the/file/path1/abcd.xml"
     >
     </test-case>

    </test-result>

 <test-result
      exectime="2017-07-07"
      result="SUCCESS"
      isdone="TRUE"
      logicalname="this.is.test1"
      duration="10050"
     >
    <test-case
     testcasename="this.is.test.case.name1"
     testunit="abcd-mc"
     testpath="file:/this/is/the/file/path1/uvwx.xml"
    >

   </test-case>
  </test-result>
```

Note that the 2 blocks of code within `<test-result></test-result>` tags differ in case of the `testpath`. So, I want to `grep` for the `logicalname` and the `result` (`grep` `this.is.test1` AND `FAILURE`) and find the respective `testpath` for the same block.

Next, once I have the `testpath` for the `FAILURE` scenario, how can I modify the file to make the result to `SUCCESS` for the block with the "`testpath` that I found" and the `logicalname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With having note that "Parsing XML is bad practice", here is an `awk` solution for your question : )

```
awk -v RS="<test-result" '
    /logicalname="this\.is\.test1"/&&/result="FAILURE"/ {
    sub("FAILURE","SUCCESS")
}1' RS='' infile.txt
```

At above, we are telling `awk` that **R**ecord **S**eperator `RS` is `<test-result`, then for each record will look the both PATTERNs (`logicalname="this.is.test1"` and `result="FAILURE"`), if it was there (within a same block) then change `FAILURE` to `SUCCESS` from given `infile.txt`

As we talked in comments since you want to change specific block with `testpath=....`, you can add another 3rd condition to the command only. below will change only if `testpath="file:/this/is/the/file/path1/abcd.xml"` also seen.

note that you need to escape `/`, and better to escape `.`s as well.

```
awk -v RS="<test-result" '  /logicalname="this\.is\.test1"/&&/result="FAILURE"/&&/testpath="file:\/this\/is\/the\/file\/path1\/abcd\.xml"/
    {sub("FAILURE","SUCCESS")
}1' RS='' infile.txt
```

Comment: "Don't do it, but I'll help you do it anyway"? (-;

Answer (score 2):

My advice is **"Don't even bother trying to do this with `grep`"**.  You could possibly knock up some unreliable regexp-based hack in `awk` or `perl`, but regular expressions can't **reliably** be used to parse or extract data from XML.  And whatever you came up would most likely be an unreadable and unmaintainable mess.  There are better ways.  Ways that actually work, and work reliably.

In short: Don't parse XML or HTML [with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  It [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/137158).

Instead, use an xml parser like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).   Alternatively, use a language like `perl` or `python`, both of which have several XML parsing libraries to choose from.

If you really want to process XML with line-oriented tool likes `grep` (or better yet, `awk` or `perl`, or even `sed`), first convert the xml to a line-oriented format with [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/).   This is not a bad option for very simple extraction of data from XML files.

e.g. after fixing up the most obvious errors with your sample xml, here's what it looks like after processing with `xml2`:

```
$ xml2 < ajs.xml 
/xml/test-result/@exectime=2017-07-07
/xml/test-result/@result=FAILURE
/xml/test-result/@isdone=TRUE
/xml/test-result/@logicalname=this.is.test1
/xml/test-result/@duration=10050
/xml/test-result/test-case/@testcasename=this.is.test.case.name1
/xml/test-result/test-case/@testunit=abcd-mc
/xml/test-result/test-case/@testpath=file:/this/is/the/file/path1/abcd.xml
/xml/test-result
/xml/test-result/@exectime=2017-07-07
/xml/test-result/@result=SUCCESS
/xml/test-result/@isdone=TRUE
/xml/test-result/@logicalname=this.is.test1
/xml/test-result/@duration=10050
/xml/test-result/test-case/@testcasename=this.is.test.case.name1
/xml/test-result/test-case/@testunit=abcd-mc
/xml/test-result/test-case/@testpath=file:/this/is/the/file/path1/uvwx.xml
```

It would be difficult to get what you want from that using only `grep`, but fairly easy with either `perl` (just simple perl without using an XML library) or `awk`, and not too difficult with `sed`.

Using `xmlstarlet` or an XML parsing library in `perl` or `python` or whatever would be even easier.   All of these methods work directly with the structured data in an XML document, i.e. will deal with each XML element as a distinct object with selectable attributes and values, not just a bunch of lines that may be somehow connected.

BTW, there are numerous questions with good answers about both [xmlstarlet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=xmlstarlet) and [xml2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=xml2) here on this site.

Both `xml2` and `xmlstarlet` are available pre-packaged for most linux distributions.

Finally, try to start with at least reasonably well-formed XML.   Your sample XML above has several flaws.  Broken, incomplete, or sub-standard XML input will be very difficult to parse with any tool.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I am not aware of perl/python :( Will try to see how can I get it done using awk or sed . Thanks again :)

Comment: if you can learn awk, you can learn perl.  really, they're not that dissimilar for the basic stuff, it's just that perl can do a lot more and has a huge collection of library modules to do almost anything you can image.  and python is pretty easy too (and also has an extensive library of pre-written functions you can call on).

Comment: but if you want to do it in awk or sed, use `xml2` rather than trying to extract from the XML file directly.  It will be **much** easier, much of the work will have been done for you, and you'll have consistently formatted input to process.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Can you give a few pointers on xml2? Like is that a package which needs to be installed or a separate tool altogether?

Comment: it's a separate program.  on debian or similar, just `apt-get install xml2`.  I expect that there are packages for fedora/centos and other distros too.   If not, the source is available in the link I gave in my answer.  Apart from that, there's really not much more to it than the example in my answer - that's what it does: convert XML input to a fairly simple line-oriented format.

Comment: btw, one thing I forgot to mention before - the `xml2` package also contains a `2xml` program which does the reverse of `xml2`, converts that semi-structured key=val format to XML.  It also contains `csv2` and `2csv` programs to convert to/from CSV.  and `html2` & `2html` - guess what they do? :)